# using default value with an ejs filter

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

If item.description is undefined or empty, I want to default to 'No description':

I've tried the following:

```
  <%-: ( item.description | markdown ) || '<p>No description</p>' %>
  <%-: ( item.description || 'No description' ) | markdown %>
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you can mix `||` with the `|` of EJS' [filters](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#filters), but you can [add a filter](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#adding-filters) to accomplish it:

```
ejs.filters.or = function (arg, sub) {
  return arg || sub;
};
```

```
<%-: item.description | or:'No description' | markdown %>
```

Comment: What will be the arguments to markdown then? edit: This works.

Comment: I've filed a PR to include this "default" filter in ejs: https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/pull/162

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering the code with your question, why the pre-tag with ejs template expression is `"<%-" not the "<%="` (the output or value assignment output) or  the `"<%=:"` (the filter output)  signature?

BTW, the filter invoke signature is the single vertical bar not double, and you can invoke any times with what you want...

Comment: markdown produces html, so you need <%- not <%= otherwise it gets escaped.